# Display Tableau dashboard on Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am using the following code to inject a tableau dashboard in my website but the dashboard only shows on 2/3 of the page. Did I do something wrong? This is my first attempt with Vue so any inputs would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import "vue-tableau";
<div class="col-md-12 mt-2 mb-2">
 <Tableau
          
url="https://public.tableau.com/shared/HRX9FWBF3?:display_count=y&:origin=viz_share_link"
ref="tableau"
  >
 </Tableau>
</div>
```

[Output on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nju4r.png)

Comment: Seems like it may be an issue with the height of the `div` tag